# Hibernate Validator 4+. Get all Constraints associated with a class

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

How can I get all constraints for a class. For instance I have

```
class A {
   @NotNull
   private SomeBean field;
}
```

When I call:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator(); 
Set<ConstraintDescriptor<?>> descriptor =  validator.getConstraintsForClass(formClass).getConstraintDescriptors();
```

The set is empty. 
I would assume there is already some functionality in Hibernate Validator that would give me all the information about constraints in a neat way , without me having to resort to the reflection api.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need them? I'm usually more interested by the violations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getConstraintsForClass()` returns constraints on the class itself. To get constraints on properties, you should call `getConstrainedProperties()`.

Comment: Thanks, 
Just a side note the getConstrainedProperties() is available in 
Hibernate Validator v 4.1.0Final for some reason it's not in the main repository, but you can find it here URL: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
For those who use some king of dependency management tool like  Maven anyway